# Reportlab + SimpleDocTemplate + Table - create QR code with text - multiple pages

Tags: python, barcode, reportlab

I'm using Reportlab to create a pdf file that can span across multiple pages with the following format:

QR code + h1 paragraph + 2-3 lines of text

We need to support a dynamic number of elements with the format I described above.

I was thinking of using a Table inside a SimpleDocTemplate but couldn't find a way to support dynamic number of elements than can span over multiple pages.

How would you tackle this challenge?

Comment: Long time i didn't use reportlab but did you check PageTemplate ?

Comment: No, is it suitable for my task?

Comment: With PageTemplate, you will be able to create a template for this situation : QR code + h1 paragraph + 2-3 lines of text

Comment: Do you have a snippet I could use?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is not fully working, but it could help you, for start

```
class StandardReport:

def __init__(self,):
    self.doc = BaseDocTemplate(destinationPath , showBoundary = 0, leftMargin=0.7*cm, rightMargin=0.7*cm, topMargin=0.7*cm, bottomMargin=0.7*cm, pagesize=A4)
    self.simpleFrame = Frame(self.doc.leftMargin, self.doc.bottomMargin, self.doc.width, self.doc.height - 5*cm, id='normal')

def createPdf(self):
    templates = [];
    self.doc.totalPages = 0;

    self.fill_sample();
    templates.append(SamplePageTempalte(self));
    self.doc.totalPages = self.doc.totalPages + 1;

    self.doc.addPageTemplates(templates);
    self.doc.build(self.Elements)

class SamplePageTempalte (PageTemplate):
    def __init__ (self, context):
        self.context = context
        self.largeur = self.context.doc.pagesize[0]
        self.hauteur = self.context.doc.pagesize[1]
        self.simpleFrame = Frame( self.context.doc.leftMargin, self.context.doc.bottomMargin, self.context.doc.width, self.context.doc.height - 3*cm, id='normal')
        PageTemplate.__init__ (self, id="GraphStatPageTemplateMonth", frames = [self.simpleFrame], pagesize=A4, onPage = self.context.footerAndHeader)
```